# Querying on the properties of a private reference

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a class that is many-to-one with its parent. I'd like to expose the parent's properties through the child without exposing the parent directly. I'd also like to query on and order by those properties.

*Classes*

```
public class Organization
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsNonProfit { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    private Organization _organization;
    public virtual string OrganizationName 
        { get { return _organization.Name; } }
    public virtual bool OrganizationIsNonProfit 
        { get { return _organization.IsNonProfit; } }
}
```

*Mapping*

```
public class OrganizationMap : ClassMap<Organization>
{
    public OrganizationMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.IsNonProfit);
    }
}

public class ContactMap : ClassMap<Contact>
{
    public ContactMap()
    {
        References<Organization>(Reveal.Member<Contact>("_organization"))
            .Access.CamelCaseField();
    }
}
```

*Query*

```
public class Example
{
    private ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    public Example(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        _sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Contact> DoQuery(int forPage, int rowsPerPage)
    {
        using (var session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            return session.Query<Contact>().OrderBy(x => x.OrganizationName)
                .Skip((forPage - 1) * rowsPerPage).Take(rowsPerPage);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that this results in a "Could not resolve property: OrganizationName" error. It looks like I could map those fields with a formula, but then I'd end up with a sub-select for each field on a table that's already joined into my query. Alternatively, I could wrap the Contact's organization with a public getter and change my query to OrderBy(x => x.Organization.Name). That leaves me with a Law of Demeter violation though.

Am I off track? How should I handle this?

*edited to show paging*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use non-mapped properties in queries. How should NHibernate know how to create a SQL condition for it? In your case it might be easy, but what if you'd have a call to a method or some complicated logic in that property?

So yes, you need at least a public getter property.

Alternatively, do the sorting in memory (after NHibernate has executed the query).

Comment: Thanks; in practice I'm combining the sort with paging so in memory sorting wouldn't be practical. With the public getter you're advocating the LoD violation then? I'm considering it; I just don't know where I'd stop. What happens when it's session.Query<Contact>().Where(x => Organization.HeadQuarters.Location.City == "Miami")?

Comment: @Eric Yes, either that or formula properties (which could result in bad SQL performance). At least for Linq queries, I don't know if there is way in Criteria/QueryOver.